# Gradle multi-module Spring Boot web application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, gradle, spring-boot, multi-module

Here I come with general philosophical quesion about organizing app with next parameters:

- I want have my webapp(html, js, css) in absolutely separate module called for example 'webapp'. No java or another class can be in this module. (and Spring Boot runners too. In all tutorials I googled webapp inner content was located in resource subfolder of module where Spring Boot app runners was)
- My controllers have to be in module 'presentation'. (I use Spring MVC)
- I want to run all this goods with Spring Boot.

Now, questions:
1.How I have to organize by build.gradle files 
2.Where have I to put Spring Boot runners 
3.In which way can I specify for Spring Boot that my web inner content located in separate module?

UPD:
After lot of googling I find solution. From version 4.1 Spring propose to get a path to web directory from properties. For more information you can look at project sagan: https://github.com/spring-io/sagan and on this video tutorial devoted to Resource Handling in Spring 4.1
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71NVb3vMvMc

Also assuming big amount of data presented in those tutorials I made up a little project where this technique implemented:
https://github.com/SergiySobolev/gradle-spring-boot

Hope it can be useful for someone